# SSRS - Trend Indicator regarding the last month

Tags: sql-server, matrix, reporting-services, indicator

I've the following dataset:

```
System_Name Description Month   Year    Value_used  YTD
APP01           PC A     4      2016      93         -
APP01           PC A     5     2016       90        1
APP01           PC A     6     2016       97        1
APP01          PC A      7     2016       82        -1
APP01          PC A      8     2016       99        1
CCD12          PC B      4     2016       81        -
CCD12          PC B      5     2016       83        1
CCD12          PC B      6     2016       83        0
CCD12          PC B      7     2016       87        1
CCD12          PC B      8     2016       88        1
```

This dataset is result from the following query:

```
SELECT *,
CASE WHEN Collect_Usage > PreviousQuota THEN 1 
                    WHEN Collect_Usage = PreviousQuota THEN 0
                    ELSE -1
            END AS [Flag Indicator]

FROM (
        SELECT System_Name,
                    [Description],
                    [Monh],
                    [Year],
                    LAG(Value_used, 1,0) OVER (ORDER BY System_Name, [Description],[Year],[Monh]) AS PreviousQuota  
        FROM [CAPM_Reporting_Analytics].[dbo].[Capacity_Data_Reds] 
        ) TB1
```

I am creating the YTD to use in my matrix on SSRS that is creating the pivot to show the evolution from month.

My problem is: Imagine that I want to create the report from Month 8. I want to add a indicator that shows
 - If the last month (only consider the month 8 in this case) is above the previous month then Green
 - If the previous month is null then Grey
 - Else Red.

I want to get anything like this:

[image]

Where the trend is  only valid between the value of the last and penultimate column (last and penultimate)

How can I do this?

Many thanks!!

Comment: PS: If you can see the trend in my image is wrong

Comment: I could see coming up with some crazy expression involving lookups that would work (add rank to query, grab max rank, lookup max rank minus 1, compare values in switch etc...) or even a custom code solution where you pass in the rowset of data and get the trend returned,  but there has to be a cleaner way; I'm just not seeing it right now.